# Orderby price doesn't work with dynamic parameters - {exp:store:search}

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I'm trying to build some filtering into my store listing. The standard 'low to high' and 'high to low' kind of thing.

Dynamic Parameters seemed like a good option

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/dynamic_parameters.html

By using $_GET variables, I'm able to control the `sort` & `orderby` parameters. However, when I set `?orderby=price` on my url, the filtering doesn't work.

`?orderby=title` works. `?sort=asc/desc` works.

Price seems to be the only thing that doesn't. I'm wondering if this is a bug. Since the `{exp:store:search}` tag augments the native entries tag, maybe something is getting lost in translation.

Below is an abstract of my code:

```
{exp:store:search
  channel="shop"
  limit="12"
  dynamic_parameters="orderby|sort"
  dynamic="yes"
  paginate="bottom"
  show_future_entries="yes"}

  < Markup in here >

{/exp:store:search}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Store search tag supports dynamic parameters for internal Store fields.

To work around this, you could put the orderby/sort parameters into segment variables (for example, `orderby="{segment_3}"`.

Alternatively, you could use one of the many EE extensions which allow you to access GET variables as early parsed EE template vars.